# as3 air unloadAndStop() event listener or timer

Tags: actionscript-3, air

my air application plays an external swf over and over until time to play the next external swf. in order to avoid memory leaks i am using unloadAndStop(). i am using two timers. the first unloadAndStops the swf. the second waits two seconds then loads it back up again.

this approach (coupled with the use of weak references) seems to keep the memory in check. however, i'd rather not use timers but event listeners. is there an event listener for when unloadAndStop completes to then load the swf again.

here is what i had in mind:

```
var TIMER_INTERVAL:int = int(duration);
var t:Timer = new Timer(TIMER_INTERVAL);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,updateTimer,false,0,true);
t.start();

private function updateTimer(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    swfLoader.unloadAndStop(true);      
    swfLoader.addEventListener(Event.UNLOAD,onSWFUnloadComplete,false,0,true);
}

private function updateTimer(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    var swfSource2:String = File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath.toString();
    swfLoader.load(swfSource2+'\\'+name_xml);
}
```

Comment: `unloadAndStop` is not an asynchronous method, so an unload event isn't appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the response. if unloadAndStop is synchronous, then why doesn't function {swfLoader.unloadAndStop(true); swfLoader.load(swfSource2+'\\'+name_xml);} do a better job of managing memory?

Comment: once swf is done playing i want to unloadAndStop it then immediately start it up again. i thought by doing it synchronously it would control memory leaks. the problem is it doesn't work.

Comment: I've never experimented with loading it again on the same frame you unload it, seems like you'd want to just fix the memory leak (unless you don't have access to the source code of the loaded file).  This is just a guess, but you might just need to wait one frame for all the cleanup stuff in the unloadAndStop to be effective.

Comment: you nailed it. i just want to fix the memory leak. i'll stick with my timer approach as it is easier to handle "waiting one frame" then updating the code that creates the swf. i would like to see unloadAndStop fixed. from what i read its a bug: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-28808. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unloadAndStop` is not an asynchronous method, so an unload event wouldn't really be relevant.   What is likely happening behind the scenes is that it takes 1 full frame to fully dispose of the movies objects/listeners and that's why you're having issues loading it again in the same block of code.

If you wait just one frame before loading it again, you should have the results you expect.

Now, of course the best solution is go into the source file of your loaded swf and fix the memory leaks.